# Can single Kafka producer produce messages to multiple topics and how?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am just exploring `Kafka`, currently i am using One `producer` and One topic to produce messages and it is consumed by one `Consumer`. very simple.

I was reading the Kafka page, the `new Producer API is thread-safe` and sharing single instance will improve the performance.

Does it mean i can use single Producer to publish messages to multiple topics?

Comment: Yes, see the docs at http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerapi.

Comment: @miguno I see almost nothing about the question in the link provided. It's about the dependency only :(

Comment: In the docs above (short section) there's a direct link to the [Java docs of `KafkaProducer<K,V>`](http://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html), see the sentence "Examples showing how to use the producer are given in the [javadocs](http://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html).".  That page has a code example that shows how you can define the destination topic when sending a message.  Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never tried it myself, but I guess you can. Since the code for producer and sending the record is (from here https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html):

```
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
 for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my-topic", Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));
```

So, I guess, if you just write different topics in the `ProducerRecord`, than it should be possible.

Also, here http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#producerapi it explicitly says that you can use a method  `send(List<KeyedMessage<K,V>> messages)` to write into multiple topics.

Comment: FWIW, the latest Kafka docs for the Producer API are at http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerapi (the link above is for the old 0.8.1 version of Kafka.

Comment: Where exactly does the producerapi section says about the method?

Comment: The producerapi section says: "Examples showing how to use the producer are given in the [javadocs](http://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html).".  That page has a code example that shows how you can define the destination topic when sending a message.

Comment: The matter of fact doing so meke the writing process of the producer slow. Has anybody checked the performance of the producer which writes on multiple topics?

Comment: @RadioLog, so can we produce message to multiple topics all having different jaas.conf (keytab and pricipal) ? Pls see my questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58313628/948268

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are more looking using the same producer instance to send the same/multiple messages on multiple topics.

Not sure about java, but here you can do in C#(.NET) using the [Kafka .NET Client](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/dotnet.html) **DependentProducerBuilder**

```
   using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(config).Build())
        using (var producer2 = new DependentProducerBuilder<Null, int>(producer.Handle).Build())
        {
            producer.ProduceAsync("first-topic", new Message<string, string> { Key = "my-key-value", Value = "my-value" });

            producer2.ProduceAsync("second-topic", new Message<Null, int> { Value = 42 });

            producer2.ProduceAsync("first-topic", new Message<Null, int> { Value = 107 });

            producer.Flush(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
```