# Kafka TopicAuthorizationException due to incorrect jaas.conf

Tags: authentication, apache-kafka, jaas

I am referring to [JAAS Login Configuration File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/LoginConfigFile.html). It talks about 2 ways to specify which login configuration file to be used:

1. The first approach where we set the `jaas.conf` through VM arg `java.security.auth.login.config`.
2. Second through the security properties file is the `java.security` file located in the `lib/security` directory of the JRE. In the second approach we can specify multiple files.

Is there a way to specify multiple jaas.conf files using the first approach of setting VM arg `java.security.auth.login.config`? Or if you have any other suggestion on solving the issue.

**Background:**
The issue which I am facing is: we have 2 different type of Kafka events (say *ABC* and *XYZ*) and their corresponding `jaas.conf` with diffrent *Keytab* and *principal*. When it wants to publish *ABC* it sets the `java.security.auth.login.config` property to *ABC's* *jaas.conf* and change to *XYZ's* *jaas.conf* when we want to publish that.

However the above logic has some issue and it fails with `org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics` for the second event that it tries to publish. An initial look at the cause looks like even for second event it tries to use the `jaas.conf` of the first one.

**Stacktrace:**

```
org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [XYZ]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate$1.onCompletion(KafkaTemplate.java:341)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:827)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:768)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:272)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:327)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:197)
```